# How to encrypt a .jar file

Tags: java, encryption, ant, public-key-encryption

I'm working in a project where we need to encrypt the .jar file so no one can access to the .class files which inside the jar file.... is there any java coding which can help me to encrypt the .jar file ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if you encrypt the jar file, it must be decrypted before the JVM is able to run it, so you'll need another jar file containing classes that decrypt and loads in the JVM.

Since this second jar file cannot be itself encrypted, a malicious user wanting to see you class files, can simply look at classes in this second jar file, and then decrypt your super-secret jar file and have access to it.

Maybe you can increase security of your code using an obfuscator, but it will eventually protect (make it harder but not impossible) your class files from decompilation, not from being used.

If obfuscation is not enough, you could consider compiling your jar file to a DLL for windows or a SO for unix/linux, that will make it much harder to decompile, but it's not always possible to do that correctly and it's generally a PITA. GCJ is able to do this somehow, and there are other commercial products that will actually compile .class/.jar directly to machine code.

However please consider that it does not matter how much security you put in it, since the client computer MUST be able to execute it, it must be able to read it, so no matter what your code will be exposed, you can only make it harder.

If you really have an algorithm so secret you don't want to disclose no matter what, consider converting it to a web service, hosting it on your server, so that you don't have to send the actual code to the client machines and can also better prevent unauthorized copies of your application by checking access to that vital part of it.

Comment: actually i want to protect the .class file from access in side the .jar file, do you got anyway to do this ?

Comment: The AlexR suggestion is to use a custom classloader that will decrypt on-the-fly the jar file, which is feasible and more or less what you were asking, but keep in mind that any average-skilled programmer with JAD installed will be able to reverse engineer your custom classloader and access the class anyway. I added a paragraph with another solution, but it's quite unusual.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are aware of the fact that any skilled java coder can reverse-engineer the Java tool you use (or write) and still decode the app's jars? Also writing custom classloaders which read your "encrypted" code can be decompiled and a tool could be written to bypass it.

Even with obfuscation and bytecode modification and custom classloaders, java is hackable/decompileable and the source can almost always be brought to a somewhat readable state.

Answer (score 3):

You want to obfuscate, not encrypt, the jar file.

A popular choice for doing this in Java is [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

No. Since your program needs to be able to run the code it would be pointless anyway.

You can obfuscate your code though so decompiling the .class files results in less readable code (meaningless variable/class names etc).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not supported by standard JVM. But you can do the following. Separate your application into 2 parts. First will not be encrypted. It will be a simple loader that will instantiate the rest using custom class loader. This class loader will get Classes as arrays of bytes, decrypt and load them.

Comment: Although this is an approach some people do use, there's always the possibility to decompile the custom classloader and break the security. Just like you can read the decrypted code, you can write it out as decrypted. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to provide an access to the class files inside the jar, why should you supply your jar with the application?
It feels like your question is kind of wrong conceptually...

If you need some custom way of loading the classes, consider to use custom classloader.

Comment: with what application i can supply my .jar file to save the .class files from access in side the .jar file ??

Answer (score 0):

if you are packaging in jar -> just rename it to jarname.ABCD or any misleading extension or even take off the extension, and accordingly specify the jar name in your application.

Comment: `file(1)` is a beautiful thing.

Answer (score -1):

i prefer [jCrypt](http://redpois0n.com/download.php?proj=jcrypt)!
It is a simple tool where you can crypt the classes(and ressources)

Answer (score -1):

You can try https://bce.gopiqiu.com/
Here is description: BCE is a java jar/war/class encrypt tools,it can leave your code avoid decompile; support format:jar,springbootjar,war; support spring and tomcat classfile scan before classes are loaded; support embedded jar encryption and prevent any program dump decrypted class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).