# How secure my Executable jar file

Tags: java, jar

I developed a desktop application in Java. I converted my code in the form of Executable jar (.jar) format. Here my problem is, this jar files easily extracted by winrar/winzip. My Java class files are visible to others and also i do De-compilation process using JAD my source code are visible to everyone. is any way to protect my source code from De-compileation process.

Comment: You can obfuscate method names and the code, but you can't really prevent decompilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt a .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187883/how-to-encrypt-a-jar-file)

Comment: Duplicate?.. please refer this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't 100% stop decompilation but you can [*obfuscate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) your code that will be hard to read once after decompilation

Comment: Thanks Jigar Joshi,I'm new to this any reference for "Obfuscate"

Answer (score 1):

As Jigar Joshi said you can obfuscate your jar file. Proguard is a good one. Here's the link to it. http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators. Alternately you can convert jar to exe using jar to exe converter. You can download it here. But you have to purchase it. http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/.

Answer (score 0):

Put a password or licence check at start of application. With proper authentication, only user must be able to run the application further.

For password check, you should generate private-public key concepts. For licence, some installed software or attached hardware can be use to provide access.