# Encrypting Android code?

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, obfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187883/how-to-encrypt-a-jar-file)

I know obfuscation but what it does is only to make the code harder to understand. It doesn't really encrypt the code. Is there a way to encrypt Android code? Or is there any alternative to make the code more irrecoverable when decompiled?

I am asking this question to know if what I'm looking for is possible. Right now, my mind suggest that it is impossible to encrypt the code since if we encrypt it, Dalvik also won't be able to understand the code and run it. But I'm not really sure about it. It is possible that I didn't know something.

Please post what do you think about this or if you have any suggestions? Also, please consider a financial application wherein having access to a human readable code means being able to understand the flow of the financial process going-on on the backend. Thank you!

Comment: *"Please post what do you think about this"*  I think it is silly.  1) Nobody wants to steal your code. 2) If the app. turns out to be a 'killer app.', it usually ends up a better clone if you get one group of people to describe the inputs and outputs, then a group of programmers to program them.  -- It is cheaper, better, and legal.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm not concerned about somebody stealing codes. I asked the question above because I'm concerned on what sensitive information others can get from reading the code.

Comment: @Arci There will always be a risk of someone reverse-engineering your code and understanding how it works. Start with the assumption that the code will get decompiled and studied, and do your best to design software that protects its users and their data *anyway*. If a system is secure, it should be possible for its design to be made public without compromising the system or its users.

Comment: *"what sensitive information others can get from reading the code."*  All of it.  The binary has to be decrypted at some stage, and the sensitive information stolen then.

Comment: @acj: Thanks for your reply! :) I agree with you that it all lies on the system in the end. But is encrypting the code on Android possible or not? Or is obfuscation really the best I can do to protect my code from being understood?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes, I'm aware of it. But is there a way to make things a lot harder for the hacker to get the sensitive information?

Comment: *"But is there a way to make things a lot harder for the hacker to get the sensitive information?"*  Put all the sensitive stuff on the server side and never expose it to end users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different efforts to make life harder for standard DEX decompiler tools, by hiding code, inserting dummy instructions, etc. It is all pretty much research stage ATM, but you can  find papers an presentations about it online, with some sample tools.

There is also [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) (not free) by the author of ProGuard which can encrypt strings (standard obfuscation does not) to make it harder to search for things in decompiled code. I haven't personally used it, but you might want to give it a try.

Ultimately though, to be able to run something you have to decrypt/descramble/whatver so you can feed it to the VM. If you have complete control over the device (i.e., root privileges and physical access), you can dump memory, introduce hooks in system libraries, etc. and get the actual runnable code. As suggested by others, if you have really sensitve code, it should live on your servers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will research more on DexGuard! :) If it can encrypt Strings, it will make life a lot easier. This is the 1st time I heard about DexGuard. Aside from DexGuard, is there a tool that can encrypt Android source codes? Or are the available tools on the net can only obfuscate codes and not encrypt them?

Comment: See first paragraph, there are experimental tools, but those are not suitable for real projects.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the machine has to be able to read your code.  Therefore...anyone with a machine can read your code.

The only alternatives to this are e.g. forcing users to contact your third-party site and get information from you there somehow.

Comment: Yes, by definition, anyone with a machine can read the code. But it is because the code is machine readable. Is there a way to make it not readable by human? Obfuscation adds to the difficulty of understanding the code. But it is not enough. Is there a better approach to hide the code from hackers? I'm thinking of encrypting the code but is there such a thing? Please take note that I'm referring to an Android application.

Comment: Given that a hacker can run the program, no, there isn't really such a thing.