# How to provide security for a jar file from decompiling the classes present in it using a manifest file

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar, code-security

Is there any attribute that is there in the manifest file to provide security to the jar file.

[update] I am working on a java swing App which will be deployed on user machine. Need to make sure that my code/app can't be tweaked or reproduced. looking for options which can help me secure my app/code.

Comment: *"..will be deployed on user machine. Need to make sure that my code/app can't be tweaked or reproduced."*  The best (and only) way to ensure that is not to distribute it at all, or if you do, write crappy code (so it's not worth stealing).  Failing that, someone else can steal it, even if it's obfuscated.

Comment: Per Dish: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187883/how-to-encrypt-a-jar-file)